# How to set the SAMPLE size in Teradata SQL by query

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

I'm working with Teradata Studio and I'm looking for a way to make the following code more maintainable, instead of this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table
SAMPLE  WHEN Language   = 'german' THEN 500
        WHEN Language   = 'french' THEN 600
        END
```

I would like get the sample sizes of 500 and 600 out of a table, so we don't need to
change the code if our stakeholders want to change the Sample size:

```
  SELECT    *
  FROM      TableXYZ
  SAMPLE    WHEN Language   = 'german' THEN SELECT SampleSize FROM TABLEA
            WHEN Language   = 'french' THEN SELECT SampleSize FROM TABLEB
            END
```

BUT even when I cast the result of the select-statment to INT/Numeric whatever, I get the error:
Syntax error, expected something like an integer or a decimal number or a floating point number between the 'THEN' keyword and the 'SELECT' keyword.

Is this simply not possible with the sample function?

Comment: Yes, it's simply not possible (unless you use Dynamic SQL in a Stored Procedure).

Comment: thanks a lot @dnoeth